# Table stops responding to clicks after refresh

Tags: java, jtable, jakarta-mail

I have the following code:

```
retrieveMessages.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        model.resetList();
        top.remove(scrollPane);
        folder = new getMessages().getMessagesInstance();
        folder.initGetMessages();
        model = new MessageTableModel().getModelInstance();

        table = new JTable(model);
        table.setTableHeader(null);
        System.out.println("Got to here");
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,150));
        top.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        table.setVisible(true);
        dialog.setVisible(true);        
    }
});

folder = new getMessages().getMessagesInstance();
folder.initGetMessages();
model = new MessageTableModel().getModelInstance();
table = new JTable(model);
table.setTableHeader(null);

scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,150));
top.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
        MessageTableModel model = new MessageTableModel().getModelInstance();
        try {
            String message = model.getMessage(table.getSelectedRow()).getMessage().toString();
            messageArea.setText(Jsoup.parse(message).text());
            System.out.println("Selected!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

There's some code in between the first function and the other two functions, but it doesn't edit any of the data. Here's the problem. When I load the GUI, the table responds fine, just as it should (as in the last function). However, when I activate the retrieveMessages function, it refreshes the table, but clicking on the rows does nothing now. I've tried hard coding print-outs to see if it's even getting there,and it isn't, or it just isn't working.

And yes, I tried fireDataChanged. That did literally nothing besides add an entire block of emails, that were identical to the original emails, on to the bottom of the original table. So I had a double the size table with copies of all emails twice. fireDataRowsDeleted did nothing either.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a global public table and add that to your:

```
 table.setModel(your_new_model_goes_here);
//update the global table with a new model`enter code here`
```

You are creating different table objects currently.